# Странное поведение разметки после 5 версии андроида

Tags: android, xml, android-toolbar

Есть некая разметка, приведу в пример лишь ее часть. По скроллу вверх она должна прятать `toolbar` и оставлять табы, на версии до `lolipop` все происходит как нужно.
Однако, начиная с версии 5.0 и выше, убирается лишь `status bar` и при этом `toolbar` занимает место `status bar`.

Сразу подумал на `android:fitsSystemWindow`, и все что у меня вышло - это сделать нормально на версии после 5, и полное скрытие на версиях до 5.

Раньше с подобным никогда не встречался, на мой взгляд поведение слишком странное.

Вот часть кода разметки:

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:openDrawer="start">

    <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
        android:id="@+id/coordinator"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#f5f5f5"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true">


        <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/blue_gradient">


            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="56dp"
                android:clickable="true"
                app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlwaysCollapsed"
                app:popupTheme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar"
                app:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar" />

            <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
                android:id="@+id/tabLayout"
                style="@style/MyCustomTabLayout"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="38dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="68dp"
                android:clickable="false"
                android:longClickable="false"
                android:paddingLeft="1dp"
                app:tabIndicatorColor="@android:color/white"
                app:tabIndicatorHeight="4dp"
                app:tabMode="scrollable"
                app:tabSelectedTextColor="@android:color/white"
                app:tabTextColor="@android:color/white" />


        </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>


        <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
            android:id="@+id/viewPager"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:clickable="true"
            app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />


        <FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
            android:id="@+id/framesheet"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="#ffffff"
            app:behavior_hideable="true"
            app:behavior_peekHeight="100dp"
            app:layout_behavior="com.asgard.power.ExpandedBottomSheetBehavior">


            <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:background="#ffffff">
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Это гугл опять воду мутит. В версии либ 23.3.0 всё более-менее нормально работает. На версии 23.4.0 придётся пользовать костыль проставления paddingTop тулбару

Comment: Думаю стоит просто оставаться на 23.3.0 (кстати в доках гугла [именно эта версия](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library/features.html) до сих пор прописана, а они довольно оперативно обновляют), чем подпирать костыли для бага, который наверняка исправят в следующем билде. Можно попробовать бетку 24.0.0 RC3

Comment: @pavlofff, так никакой же гарантии, что это баг и что поправят и что в следующей версии)) Гугл вообще расстраивает всё время - что не обновление - то боль( А мне нравится либы обновлять( Но вот обновишь - и сиди гугл тереби пару часов(

Comment: Ну .. гарантии конечно нет, но ранее такие вещи всегда устранялись довольно оперативно. Багрепорт уже, очевидно,  закидан этим багом, не будут же они объяснять, что это фича такая - на разных API разное поведение. 23.4.0 не принес ничего такого, из-за чего его нужно непременно использовать - [7 минорных фиксов  и один метод](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library/revisions.html). Вот если в 24.0.0 это сохранится, то уже печаль, тут поддержка API24