# Переход на 23.3.0 версию buildToolsVersion

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, java

В приложении сейчас стоит 23.0.3 версия, решил перейти на 23.3.0.
Попытался синхронизировать - пишет, что не хватает чего-то там в модуле. Пошел в настройки проекта, на что вижу ошибку `Multiple entries with same key: 24.0.0 rc4=24.0.0 rc4 and 24.0.0 rc4=24.0.0 rc4`

Смущает то, что зайдя сюда, подобных проблем ни у кого не было - сейчас пытаюсь решить ее с помощью удаления пакетов Android N и Marshmallow.

Пока всё это происходит, хотел бы услышать причину, что-бы в будущем не натыкаться более и понимать ее природу.

Comment: Не помогло, он вообще не знает про 23.3.0 версию, такого билда, мол в `SDK` не существует

Comment: Вроде как последняя стабильная версия gradle это 2.1.2

Comment: @ЮрийСПб я имел ввиду buildToolsVersion

Comment: buildToolsVersion последняя, вроде, 23.0.3

Comment: @ЮрийСПб http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/533588/%D0%A1%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BA%D0%B8-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B5-5-%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%B8-%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B4%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B8%D0%B4%D0%B0

Comment: Там речь про версии библиотек поддержки `app-compat-v7`, не про версию gradle или biuldTools. Это всё разные вещи.

Comment: @ЮрийСПб видимо, я не правильно понял, во всяком случае сейчас у меня все развалилось и работать отказывается.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. стабильная версия gradle это 2.1.2 - Она указывается в gradle файле уровня проекта.
2. buildToolsVersion последняя 23.0.3. Она указывается в gradle файле уровня модуля приложения (build.gradle(module app)).
3. Библиотеки поддержки сейчас имею версию 23.4.0, но она глючная и её надо указать как 23.3.0. `support:appcompat-v7:23.3.0`