# Проблемное скрытие тулбара

Tags: android, android-sdk, gradle, material-design

[image]

Сделал рекомендации отсюда [Странное поведение разметки после 5 версии андроида](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/533588/%D0%A1%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BA%D0%B8-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B5-5-%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%B8-%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B4%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B8%D0%B4%D0%B0]) ,однако проблема решилась ровно наполовину.

Применение `android:fitsSystemWindow` никаким образом не влияет в лучшую\худшую сторону.

Версия библиотеки поддержки: 23.3.0
Версия `gradle` 2.1.2
Версия `buildToolsVersion` 23.0.3
UPD: Добавлю код разметки `Toolbar&Tabs`

```
 <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
        android:id="@+id/coordinator"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#f5f5f5"
        android:clickable="true">


        <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/blue_gradient">


            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                android:clickable="true"
                app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlwaysCollapsed"
                app:popupTheme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar"
                app:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar" />

            <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
                android:id="@+id/tabLayout"
                style="@style/MyCustomTabLayout"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
                android:layout_marginLeft="68dp"
                android:clickable="false"
                android:longClickable="false"
                android:paddingLeft="1dp"
                app:tabIndicatorColor="@android:color/white"
                app:tabIndicatorHeight="4dp"
                app:tabMode="scrollable"
                app:tabSelectedTextColor="@android:color/white"
                app:tabTextColor="@android:color/white" />


        </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>


        <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
            android:id="@+id/viewPager"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            android:clickable="true"
            app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />
```

Comment: Попробуйте обернуть тулбар с табами в CollapsingToolbarLayout с прописанным атрибутом `app:contentScrim="@color/colorPrimary"`

Comment: И видимо стоит paddingBottom

Comment: @ЕвгенийСуетин нет, я бы сразу догадался, что дело в нём

Comment: @ЮрийСПб после Вашего совета оно стало работать как нужно, единственное - что он слегка сошел с ума.
[он выдал ошибку](https://pp.vk.me/c633816/v633816051/3cbac/Md3BH76iILM.jpg) за отсутствие класса Bottom Sheet, пришлось делать clean и rebuilt проекта, после этого все заработало, но цвет статус бара сам по себе изменился на белый, и вернуть не выходит, что-то магическое.

Comment: Проверьте что у вас в colorPrimary записано. И в colorPrimaryDark

Comment: @ЮрийСПб первым делом туда полез - все как и было, нормально. Он словно игнорирует их.

Comment: Ну, тогда посмотрите чтоб в стилях было что-то типа `translusentStatusBar="true`"

Comment: @ЮрийСПб в таком случае он `toolbar` все равно как-бы закидывает под `status bar` и возвращаемся к первоначальной проблеме - `toolbar` виден

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Решение вышло хардкодом - `android:statusBarColor>#444444`(цвет например)